# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' in python

Tags: python, networkx

I am new to python and I am trying to do the following:

1. Take an element `x` sequentially from a list `randomnodes` and append the `neighbors of x` at the end of the list.
2. Repeat this until the size of the list is 100.

The code I have written is given below:

```
for x in randomnodes:
    if len(randomnodes)<=100:
        randomnodes.append(neighbors(x))
```

where neighbors(x) returns a list.

But the code gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "randomsampling_diameter.py", line 48, in <module>
     randomnodes.append(neighbors(x))
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx-1.9.1-py2.7.egg/networkx/classes/graph.py", line 980, in neighbors
     return list(self.adj[n])
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Why is it so? How should the code be modified to achieve the task?

Comment: Will you please give full traceback? this is just 2 lines from traceback.

Comment: What is `randomnodes`?

Comment: could you print type of neighbors(x)

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: It is a list.

Comment: @duck: neighbors(x) just produces neighbors of node x in a graph (like neighbor of 2 can be 3,4,5. So, neighbors of x returns a list [3,4,5])

Comment: What input does the neighbors function try a unit test give a input to neighbors(x) see the output if that works append the output of neighbors(x) to randomnodes

Comment: @VigneshKalai: Thanks. Actually it should be `randomnodes.extend(neighbors(x))` instead of `randomnodes.append(neighbors(x))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trouble you're having is that you're adding the neighbors list to the end of `randomnodes`, rather than adding elements from the list. This leads a later iteration to try to get the neighbors of the nested neighbor list, resulting in an exception.

If you don't mind the `randomnodes` list sometimes getting a few extra elements, you could just replace `append` with `extend` in your current code.

Otherwise, try this slightly more complicated code that uses `list.extend` to add an appropriate number elements from the neighbor list to `randomnodes`, without ever making it longer than 100 items:

```
for x in randomnodes:
    neighbors_list = neighbors(x)
    if len(randomnodes) + len(neighbors_list) < 100:
        randomnodes.extend(neighbors_list)
    else:
        randomnodes.extend(neighbors_list[:100-len(randomnodes)]
        break
```

Note that neither your code, nor the code I suggest above makes any effort to ensure there are not duplicate results added to `randomnodes`. If your graph may have cycles, you might want to add some logic to avoid that situation. This can't be quite as simple as using a `set` for `randomnodes` (because you can't modify a set while you're iterating over it), but you can use a `set` of seen nodes to filter each neighbor list:

```
seen = set(randomnodes)
for x in randomnodes:
    neighbors_list = [n for n in neighbors(x) if n not in seen]
    if len(randomnodes) + len(neighbors_list) < 100:
        randomnodes.extend(neighbors_list)
        seen.update(neighbors_list)
    else:
        randomnodes.extend(neighbors_list[:100-len(randomnodes)]
        break
```

Comment: `set` would be appropriate. But as far as I remember sets can't be updated withing a loop and the code will throw an error: `RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration`. Can you update your answer using `set` too?

Comment: Your right, it's not quite a simple as I'd though. You'll need to maintain a separate `set` of nodes that you've seen while still iterating over a list that you extend as you go. I've updated my answer with another version of the code that avoids duplicating nodes.